# Awk print different character on seperate line

Tags: awk, grep

I have been search aorund and could not find the answer... wonder if anyone can help here.

suppose I have a file contents the following:

File1:

```
name Joe 
day Wednesday
lunch was fish

name John 
dinner pie
day tuesday
lunch was noodles

name Mary
day Friday
lunch was fish pie
```

I wanted to grep and print only their name and what they had for lunch.

I suppose i can do

```
cat file1 | grep -iE 'name|lunch'
```

but what if i want to do a awk to just have their name and food like this output below?

```
Joe
fish
John
noodles
Mary
fish pie
```

I am aware to use awk to print, but this may require awk, is it possible for awk to lets say print $2 on one line, and print $3 on another?

Can I also output it in this format:

```
Person food
Joe    fish
John   noodles
Mary   fish pie
```

Thanks

Comment: Mind your finger, you are un/accepting many times :D http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31958772/timeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example say:

```
$ awk '/name/ {print $2} /lunch/ {$1=$2=""; print}' file
Joe
  fish
John
  noodles
Mary
  fish pie
```

Or remove the `lunch was` text:

```
awk '/name/ {print $2} /lunch/ {gsub("lunch was ",""); print}' file
```

---

To make the output in two columns:

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" '/name/ {name=$2} /lunch/ {gsub("lunch was ",""); print name, $0}' a
Joe     fish
John    noodles
Mary    fish pie
```

Comment: You're welcome! Since you're new here, don't forget to mark an answer accepted whenever it helped (most) in understanding and solving the problem.

Answer (score 2):

#### awk

with awk you can do it in one shot,

```
awk -v RS="" '{n=$2;sub(/.*lunch was\s*/,"");print n,$0}' file
```

Note that with this one-liner, the format of your input file should be fixed. Your data should be stored in data blocks and `lunch was` line should be at the end of each data block.

test with your example:

```
kent$  awk -v RS="" '{n=$2;sub(/.*lunch was\s*/,"");print n,$0}' file 
Joe fish
John noodles
Mary fish pie
```

#### grep & sed

also you can do it in two steps, grep the values out, and merge lines

```
grep -Po 'name\s*\K.*|lunch was\s*\K.*' file|sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
```

with your input file, it outputs:

```
kent$  grep -Po 'name\s*\K.*|lunch was\s*\K.*' file|sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
Joe fish
John noodles
Mary fish pie
```